# Is it possible to transform this Heat Equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have a heat equation given as:

$\partial_{t}v + \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2s^{2}}\partial_{yy}v - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} = 0$

where $s$ is a variable and $v = v(t,y)$. Now, in the article I'm reading, it is implied that this equation can be transformed into the equation:

$\partial_{t}w + \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\partial_{xx}w + \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\partial_{x}w = 0$

where $w = w(t,x)$

I'm attempting to follow a similar method as to transforming the Black-Scholes equation into the heat equation, as given in the link: http://planetmath.org/AnalyticSolutionOfBlackScholesPDE

However, all attempts I've made have failed. Can someone provide a bit of a hint as to what should be done? Is it even possible to transform this equation?

Comment: For the first equation we start take $\tilde{y} = ys$ and $\tilde{v} = v - \frac{\sigma^2 t}{2}$ to get
$$\tilde{v}_t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\tilde{v}_{\tilde{y}\tilde{y}} = 0$$
which is a standard heat equation. For the second equation take  $w = \tilde{w} e^{-\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\sigma^2t}{8}}$ to get
$$\tilde{w}_t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\tilde{w}_{xx} = 0$$
which is also the standard heat equation. You should be able to combind this to go from one form to the other.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that! Sorry, but would it be okay if you could tell me how you obtained the relevant PDEs (e.g. $\partial_{t} \tilde{v}$,$\partial_{\tilde{y}\tilde{y}}\tilde{v}$ etc.)? I'm quite poor with PDEs as you can tell. Also, how did you find the relevant change of variables? I struggled for ages using different variables and couldn't get it, yet you found it in a matter of minutes, if even that! How did you do it?

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of experience (knowing what tends to work by having done similar things before). There are some pointers one can use: 1) constant terms (like $-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$) can be absorbed by making linear shifts of the field on the form $v \to v + At + Bx$. 2) terms like $w_{xx} + w_x$ motivates introducing "integrating factors" (since $[w_x e^x]_x = [w_{xx} + w_x]e^x$). Here a simple $w\to we^x$ thing does not work so I tried $w\to we^{ax + bt}$ instead and solved for $a,b$ to give me the desired form. This happened to work, otherwise we would have to try something else.

Comment: Okay, so I think I've managed to get everything, thanks heaps for the help!  I just have two (hopefully final) questions: Firstly, should $w = \tilde{w}e^{-\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\sigma^2 t}{8}}$ actually be $w = \tilde{w}e^{-\frac{x\sigma^2}{2} + \frac{\sigma^2 t}{8}}$? Because I only got it to work by doing it like that (unless I did it wrong, which is quite likely). Secondly, why did you choose to have $\frac{\sigma^2 t}{8}$? Wouldn't having just $w = \tilde{w}e^{-\frac{x}{2} + t}$ be sufficient? Unless I did everything wrong, which again, wouldn't be much of a shock :/

Comment: No it should just be $x$ not $x\sigma^2$. This can be understood from dimensional analysis: think of $t$ as time and $x$ as length then the unit of the first term is $1/$Time and the units of the second term is $1/$Length $\cdot$(unit of $\sigma^2$). Thus $\sigma^2$ has units $L/T$ (velocity) and $\sigma^2 t$ has unit length which agrees with $x$ (it only makes sense to add/subtract terms with the same unit so $x-\sigma^2 t = $[length-length] makes sense but $x\sigma^2 - \sigma^2 t$ [velocity*length - length] does not so if you get this you have done something wrong).

Comment: Here is what I did. If we take $w = \tilde{w}e^{ax + bt}$ then $w_t = [\tilde{w}_t + b\tilde{w}]e^{ax + bt}$, $w_x = [\tilde{w}_x + a\tilde{w}]e^{ax + bt}$ and $w_{xx} = [\tilde{w}_{xx} + 2a\tilde{w}_x + a^2\tilde{w}]e^{ax + bt}$ so 

$$w_t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}[w_{xx} + w_x] = 0 \implies \tilde{w}_t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\tilde{w}_{xx} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(2a+1)\tilde{w}_x + [b + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(a^2+a)]\tilde{w}$$
Now we see that if we take $a=-1/2$ and $b = -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(a^2+a)$ then the last two terms vanish and we get $\tilde{w}_t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\tilde{w}_{xx} = 0$

Comment: Wow, okay that clears everything up for me. Thanks heaps, you've helped alot!